# can we insert a date value when the Closing date on opportunity is Null using a before trigger?

Tags: data-loader, upsert

we are using dataloader to upsert records into Opportunity object but there might a case where there is no Closing date for some records, in that case, can we insert a particular date value using before trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Probably no, because in the [Order of Execution](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318237&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) System Validation rules are going first, before all triggers.